# bootstrap modal is not showing up on the action

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am making the use of modal in my tutorial project and I have used 
 bootstrap modal class on the "Add post" click. 
 But the problem is when I am clicking on the Add Post nothing is 
 happening 
 I am not able to find the error.

If any one knows what is the issue do suggest me.
 I have added  $("[data-toggle='modal']").modal(); in my script too.

Below is my code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<title>Blogen</title>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
  integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<header id="main-header" class="py-2 bg-primary text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Dashboard</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- ACTIONS -->
<section id="actions" class="py-4 mb-4 bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <a
          href="#"
          class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#addPostModal"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add Post
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- MODALS -->

<!-- ADD POST MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addPostModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Add Post</h5>
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span>&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value="">Web Development</option>
              <option value="">Tech Gadgets</option>
              <option value="">Business</option>
              <option value="">Health & Wellness</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image">Upload Image</label>
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image" />
              <label for="image" class="custom-file-label"
                >Choose File</label
              >
            </div>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Max Size 3mb</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="body">Body</label>
            <textarea name="editor1" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
          Save Changes
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer id="main-footer" class="bg-dark text-white mt-5 p-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p class="lead text-center">
          Copyright &copy;
          <span id="year"></span>
          Blogen
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>
  //get the current year of copyright
  $("#year").text(new Date().getFullYear());

  $("[data-toggle='modal']").modal();

  CKEDITOR.replace("editor1");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have included these scripts two times in your code, remove one of them also remove this line `$("[data-toggle='modal']").modal();` from your javascript and try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scxLqfk0/)

```
<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

Comment: I have removed one of the script and this is running in JSFiddle but not in  my project.

Comment: Removed this line also from your JS code `$("[data-toggle='modal']").modal();`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<title>Blogen</title>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
  integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header id="main-header" class="py-2 bg-primary text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Dashboard</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- ACTIONS -->
<section id="actions" class="py-4 mb-4 bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <a
          href="#"
          class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#addPostModal"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add Post
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- MODALS -->

<!-- ADD POST MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addPostModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Add Post</h5>
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span>&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value="">Web Development</option>
              <option value="">Tech Gadgets</option>
              <option value="">Business</option>
              <option value="">Health & Wellness</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image">Upload Image</label>
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image" />
              <label for="image" class="custom-file-label"
                >Choose File</label
              >
            </div>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Max Size 3mb</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="body">Body</label>
            <textarea name="editor1" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
          Save Changes
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer id="main-footer" class="bg-dark text-white mt-5 p-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p class="lead text-center">
          Copyright &copy;
          <span id="year"></span>
          Blogen
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>
  //get the current year of copyright
  $("#year").text(new Date().getFullYear());

  //$("[data-toggle='modal']").modal();

  CKEDITOR.replace("editor1");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3geojtLd/)

```js
//get the current year of copyright
//$("#year").text(new Date().getFullYear());
//$("[data-toggle='modal']").modal();

CKEDITOR.replace("editor1");
$("#year").replaceWith(new Date().getFullYear());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Blogen</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <!-- HEADER -->
  <header id="main-header" class="py-2 bg-primary text-white">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h1><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- ACTIONS -->
  <section id="actions" class="py-4 mb-4 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPostModal">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add Post
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- MODALS -->

  <!-- ADD POST MODAL -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="addPostModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Add Post</h5>
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span>&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Title</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="category">Category</label>
              <select class="form-control">
                <option value="">Web Development</option>
                <option value="">Tech Gadgets</option>
                <option value="">Business</option>
                <option value="">Health & Wellness</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="image">Upload Image</label>
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image" />
                <label for="image" class="custom-file-label">Choose File</label
              >
            </div>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Max Size 3mb</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="body">Body</label>
                <textarea name="editor1" class="form-control"></textarea>
              </div>
          </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
          Save Changes
        </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer id="main-footer" class="bg-dark text-white mt-5 p-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <p class="lead text-center">
              Copyright &copy;
              <span id="year"></span> Blogen
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <script>
    </script>
```